# Codeception acceptance tests exactly the same buttons in different forms on the same page

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing, acceptance

I have two exactly the same buttons in two different forms on the same page. Forms and buttons have no id or name and the only difference is between those forms, which is the action.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="http://mysite/one">
    <button title="" type="submit" class="button">Edit</button>
</form>

<form class="form" method="post" action="http://mysite/two">
    <button title="" type="submit" class="button">Edit</button>
</form>
```

I am writing acceptance tests in Codeception and perform those tests using PhpBrowser.

I want to click those buttons but only the first one is clicked.

This works only for the first button:

```
$I->click("button[type=submit]");
```

***Solution 1:***
I added IDs to the buttons.

***Solution 2:***

```
$I->click("//form[contains(@action,'http://mysite/two')]/button[@type='submit']");
```

Comment: It's a good practice to add IDs to anything you might want to click with a Codeception Acceptance test. It's easier, and it makes your code a lot more readable (assuming that the ids are descriptive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
$I->click("//form[contains(@action,'http://mysite/two')]/button[@type='submit']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following XPath expression:

```
$I->click('(//button[@type=submit])[2]');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working.. I tried $I->click('button[type=submit][2]'); too

Comment: Weird, try with "/descendant::button[@type='submit'][2]"

Comment: Thanks again but it's not working.. Do you know if there is any way to use form's action="http://mysite/one" for that?

Comment: Not sure. Why not just add IDs to the buttons? That's what ID is for - to provide unique identifiers for elements.